# How to link winsock library?

Tags: c++, sockets, cygwin

I'm on Windows 8 and using Cygwin, GNU vim and gdb for development. I need to link the Winsock library into my project; how can I do that?

I googled this but only found solutions for Visual Studio projects. I'm currently using the `g++` compiler provided with `cygwin`. Here's my current `makefile`:

```
 bin: main.o
        g++ -o bin main.o ws_32.lib ws2_32.lib
 main.o:
        g++ -c -g main.cpp -std=c++11
 clean:
        rm -rf *.o bin
```

But it doesn't work. The following is printed:

```
$ make
g++ -o bin main.o ws_32.lib ws2_32.lib
g++: error: ws_32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: ws2_32.lib: No such file or directory
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'bin' failed
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you try `-lws2_32` instead of `ws2_32.lib`?

Comment: @reuben Perfect, thanks. What does your example work? BTW, what about ws_32.lib?

Comment: You should remove both `ws_32.lib` and `ws2_32.lib` before trying to add `-lws2_32`.